# How do I select multiple data on R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have country data of natural disasters and economical loss. I am trying to see whether climate change intensifies natural disasters over time.
I am trying to group together natural disasters caused by climate change (Wildfire', 'Drought', 'Landslide', 'Flood') and natural disasters that are not ('Earthquake')

This is the code I have carried out:

```
climate = c('Wildfire', 'Drought', 'Landslide', 'Flood', 'Earthquake')
newdata$climate_related = ifelse(newdata$Entity %in% climate, "yes", "yes","yes","yes","no")
```

This is the Error I receive:

> Error in ifelse(newdata$Entity %in% climate, "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes",  :
> unused arguments ("yes", "yes", "no")

What am I doing wrong? And, what is the best way to carry this out?

Comment: type `?ifelse` in the console.

Answer (score 2):

We need just a 'no' as `else` as the `ifelse` takes only three arguments i.e. `test` - logical expression, `yes` - the value to replace if the condition is `TRUE`, `no-` value to replace if condition is `FALSE`.  Also, all the arguments should be of the same length.  But, if the `length` is 1, it gets recycled

```
ifelse(newdata$Entity %in% climate, "yes", "no")
```

One option if there are many elements, either collapse them as a single string

```
no_option <- toString(c("yes","yes","yes","no"))
ifelse(newdata$Entity %in% climate, "yes", no_option)
```

Or create a `list` and return as `list`

```
no_option <- list("yes","yes","yes","no")
```

Comment: I have 4 yes and 1 no. So what is the best way around to group this?